# How can I find second solution of this second order linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I know $$y_1=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$ is a solution  of ODE $$xy''+2y'+xy=0$$

How can I find second solution $y_2$, such that $$\frac{y_1}{y_2} \neq c$$ not constant.

I try to this.

$$xy''+2y'+xy=0 \\ (xy)'=y+xy' \\ (xy)''=(y+xy')'=y'+y'+xy''=2y'+xy''
\\ (xy)''+xy=0\quad,\quad z=xy\quad,\quad z''+z=0 \\ z=C_1\cos{x}+C_2\sin{x}\quad\Rightarrow\quad y=\frac{z}{x}=\frac{C_1\cos{x}+C_2\sin{x}}{x}$$

Comment: Don't see anything wrong. What do you actually want to know?

Comment: Did I solve well?? Then, is there anything way to solve this problem??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Did I solve well?". You followed the general procedure, made no mistakes in your steps and got 2 solutions as expected. Done.

Comment: I don't know how can I determine y2 that satisfied the condition y1/y2 not constant. If I use general soltion y, y1/y = c. Isn't wrong? Did I misundertand the problem?

Comment: You have it: $y_2=\cos x/x$.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$ y = C_1\frac{\sin x}{x} + C_2\frac{\cos x}{x} = C_1y_1 + C_2y_2 $$

Thus
$$ y_1 = \frac{\sin x}{x} $$
$$ y_2 = \frac{\cos x}{x} $$

which satisfies 
$$ \frac{y_1}{y_2} = \tan x \ne c$$